# Feeding a dependency in unmockable legacy code

Tags: php, unit-testing

I have a legacy class that I *quickly* want to write a couple of tests for. Unfortunately we have a singleton call  in the constructer, and not enough time at present to refactor it as it should.

```
function __construct(){

   $this->_dbConnect = DbConnect::getInstance();
  // very long constructer (sigh) omitted below ...
}
```

Is it acceptable practice to do this, so as to have mockable legacy code :

```
function __construct(DbConnect $dbConnect = null){

    $this->_dbConnect = isset($dbConnect) ? $dbConnect : DbConnect::getInstance(); 

   // <snip>
}
```

Comment: This is the suggested approach in [Sebastian Bergmann's Blog Post about Testing code that uses Singletons](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/882-Testing-Code-That-Uses-Singletons.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test only this class - **yes**, it's normal code.

*Sorry for 1-line answer, but your question contains answer already :)*

Comment: Totally appreciated your one liner. I'm new to TDD, and on a 1 man team so I just want to validate I'm on the right track when applying these methodologies.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it acceptable practice to do this, so as to have mockable legacy code :

It's a good start, I guess. Then again, if you're going to refactor the whole application, you might want to consider just requesting the DatabaseConnection via the constructor, and change all calls that would create that object. If you're only focused on testing that exact class right now, your solution is totally acceptable.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Refactoring will be scheduled in upcoming release. I just had to get the unit testing library installed & ready to roar for this app but have a bit of time left to pop in a couple of tests. ;o)